# Java Cloud APIs

Tags: java, api, groovy, amazon-web-services, eucalyptus

I'm looking to write a Java (Groovy actually) web application that will need to talk to both AWS and Eucalyptus clouds for both compute and storage.  So we're looking for a Java library that can talk to both.

I know that Eucalyptus is supposed to be AWS API compatible so anything that talks to AWS should be able to talk to Eucalyptus but that has not been my experience.  I've found some of the ec2 command line apps that should work with Eucalyptus but simply crash.

Here's what I'm considering so far:

- [typica](http://code.google.com/p/typica/)
- [jclouds](http://code.google.com/p/jclouds/)
- [Dasein](http://dasein-cloud.sourceforge.net/)
- [AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/)
- [Cloud Foundry](http://www.cloudfoundry.com)

Do anyone have experience using any of these to talk to AWS and Eucalyptus?  Are there any other similar APIs out there worth looking at?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since your doing Java/Groovy (Grails?) I would suggest adding [CloudFoundry](http://www.cloudfoundry.com/) to your short list.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I'll have a look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at libcloud's Java version (original version is in Python): https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/libcloud/sandbox/java/trunk/. Its development seems to go quite fast and the whole thing looks quite promising.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I didn't know libcloud was being ported to Java.  I'll be keeping an eye on this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you write up an API for your cloud engines for your needs, and then use a separate implementation for each backend you want.  The reason for this - makes it mockable (hence testable).

Comment: That's what the libraries I'm considering already do.  No need to write up a new one when I can reuse a library.